# Replacing double quotes within Access concatenation code

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm using [Allen Browne's concatenation code](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) in my Access database. It works well, except for the fact that some of my primary keys contain a single double-quote. This double quote throws off the SQL string being passed to the procedure, and I get **Access Error 3075** (missing operator) on the rows containing the quote. Here is an example of the output:

```
route              cables
1769               P006, P007
1769               P008, P009
4" DRILL           [blank]
```

The error occurs on the 4" DRILL line.

My VBA is the same as Allen's. My SQL:

```
SELECT tblVia_Routing.[route], 
ConcatRelated("[cable]","tblVia_Routing","[route] = """ & [route] & """") AS cables
FROM tblVia_Routing;
```

Any advice on how to escape the double quote used to denote inches? I've tried a REPLACE in the SQL, but could not get it to work.

Comment: Maybe try single quotes as `ConcatRelated("[cable]","tblVia_Routing","[route] = '" & [route] & "'")`

Comment: This worked! Fantastic, thank you.

Comment: Note that you may have the same problem later if you have some single quotes in keys.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can try this SQL:

```
SELECT tblVia_Routing.[route],
replace(ConcatRelated("[cable]","tblVia_Routing","[route] = """ & [route] & """"),"""","""""") as cables
FROM tblVia_Routing;
```

You can replace double quotes with 2 double quotes, because in Access you can escape them by duplication.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work... It adds an extra field to the query, the default Expr1001. Expr1001 has a value of -1 for all values except for the values with the double quote. I also get the same Error 3075.

The Error 3075 message says it's reading the problematic query expression as 

   '[route] = "4" DRILL"'

Comment: @Harry T I've updated my answer. I think that this should work: the replace is now done on the entire ConcatRelated function

Answer (score 0):

Access has two symbols that can be used to express string values, the single quote character `'` `Chr(39)` and the double quote character `"` `Chr(34)`.

If your values only ever contains `'`, you can enclose it with `"` and similarly if your values only ever contains `"`, you can enclose it with `'`.

If your value may alternately contains `'`, `"` or both, you will have to escape some of them in the SQL string and enclose with the symbol escaped.

Escaping a (single or double) quote in Access SQL is quite simple, it consist just in doubling it.

So using the following SQL should work, doubling the embedded `"`:

```
SELECT tblVia_Routing.[route], 
ConcatRelated("[cable]","tblVia_Routing","[route] = """ & Replace([route], """","""""") & """") AS cables
FROM tblVia_Routing;
```

or nicer by using the single quotes:

```
SELECT tblVia_Routing.[route], 
ConcatRelated("[cable]","tblVia_Routing","[route] = '" & Replace([route], "'","''") & "'") AS cables
FROM tblVia_Routing;
```